# Mapping not found

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, automapper

I've been struggling with automapper and nested objects. I get the following error:

```
Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.
AdminSchema -> Schema
```

But that doesn't seem right to me, because I do have the following mapping configured:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Schema, AdminSchema>().ReverseMap();
```

It should be mapping the following models:

```
public class AdminSchema
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Opeenvolgende weken")]
    public int ConsecutiveWeeks { get; set; }

    public List<AdminWorkDay> WorkDays { get; set; }

    public bool Delete { get; set; }
}

public class AdminWorkDay
{
    public int DayOfWeekNumber { get; set; }
    public string StartTime { get; set; }
    public string EndTime { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan BreakTime { get; set; }
    public bool Delete { get; set; }
}
```

To

```
public class Schema
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int ConsecutiveWeeks { get; set; }
    public List<WorkDay> WorkDays { get; set; } 
}

public class WorkDay
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int DayOfWeekNumber { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndTime { get;set; }
    public TimeSpan BreakTime { get; set; }
}
```

For the string to datetime mapping, I have the following code:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<string, DateTime>().ConvertUsing<StringToDateTimeConverter>();

public class StringToDateTimeConverter : ITypeConverter<string, DateTime>
{
    public DateTime Convert(ResolutionContext context)
    {
        var sourceDt = context.SourceValue;
        DateTime targetDt;

        if (sourceDt == null)
        {
            return default(DateTime);
        }
        return DateTime.TryParse(sourceDt.ToString(), out targetDt) ? targetDt : default(DateTime);
    }
}
```

And here is the implementation of the mapping:

```
var workPeriod = new WorkPeriod {
            Schemas = Mapper.Map<List<AdminSchema>, List<Schema>>(workPeriodVm.Schemas)
        };
```

If anyone might have an idea as to why it doesn't find my mapping, please let me know. It will be much appreciated. Other mappings do work so thec onfiguration of automapper in general is correct.

Comment: Why are you using ReverseMap?

Comment: Because for the detail page i have to map the other way around, or is using ReverseMap bad practice?

Comment: I use it - it's necessary if you map from/to the specified types. Do you have mappings for `WorkDay` and `AdminWorkDay`?

Comment: @Ric, yes I do: Mapper.CreateMap<WorkDay, AdminWorkDay>().ReverseMap();

Comment: I tested you code and it works here. Are you sure you are not missing something here? What version of AutoMapper are you using?

Comment: agree with @YacoubMassad - I've tested it and got not problems either!

Comment: @YacoubMassad Im using 4.0.4.0

Comment: Same here. I think that the code that has the issue is somehow different from the code in the question.

Comment: The code posted here is the same as in my editor, Ill try to find something else in my code. Thanks anyways guys

Comment: I am having a similar issue - were you able to find the issue at the time?

Answer (score 0):

Obviously types of `WorkDays` in TSource and TDestination aren't equal, while you have to set TSource and TDestination types equal in AutoMapper Nuget Package.
for example change TSource and TDestination types to `AdminWorkDay` for `WorkDays` properties and you see it works properly.